# Searching for a specific DateTime in a SQL Database(WebMatrix)

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, search, webmatrix

I'm trying to search a SQL database for a specific set of DateTime items. My intention is to be able to search for a specific date, and then getting log data of that data onto the screen in a WebGrid.

I would appreciate any tips and help i can get since i'm fairly new to programming

My Initial Error:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The data type is not valid for the boolean operation. [ Data type (if known) = datetime,Data type (if known) = nvarchar

The full set of code is below here:

```
 @{
var db = Database.Open("Cafeen");

var grid = new WebGrid();
if (IsPost) {
    var SearchTerm = Request["Data"];
    var selectcommand = "SELECT * FROM logistics WHERE Date > SearchTerm";
    var dw = Convert.ToDateTime(SearchTerm);
    var SelectedData = db.Query(selectcommand, dw);
    grid = new WebGrid(source: SelectedData, defaultSort: "Stock", rowsPerPage:50);
}
}
</form>
<h1>Search for Log files</h1>
<form method="post">
    <div id="grid">
            Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30" value="@Request["Data"]" />
            <input type="submit" />
            <hr/>
            @if (IsPost) {
                    @grid.GetHtml(
                        tableStyle: "grid",
                        headerStyle: "head",
                        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                            grid.Column("ProductName"),
                            grid.Column("Category"),
                            grid.Column("Price"),
                            grid.Column("PurchasePrice"),
                            grid.Column("Stock"),
                            grid.Column("Date")
        )
    )
            }
    </div>
</form>

<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#format" ).change(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  But the way that you pass parameters into a SQL string is through something called parameterization.  Your first parameter in the SQL string will be @0, the second @1, and so on.  Those will correspond to the first parameter passed in the db.Query().  So you can think of it as db.Query( string, @0, @1,....).  So to your specific case, i would change the sql a bit to look at just the date and then use the parameter:

```
var selectcommand = "SELECT * FROM logistics WHERE Date > @0";
```

and then your query line will look like:

```
var SelectedData = db.Query(selectcommand, dw);
```

and your dw variable is placed into the @0 part of the string.  By the way, parameterization protects you from a nasty security vulnerability called SQL injection attack.

Comment: Even with your advice i cannot get it to run i get the following error      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The specified data type is not     valid. [ Data type (if known) = date ]

Comment: As a test, change your line to
    var selectcommand = "SELECT * FROM logistics WHERE CONVERT(date, getdate()) = '5/6/2016'";

where the date is one that's actually in your database and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately the error error message remains the same,

Comment: That makes it sound like the Date field is not really a dateTime.   I also noticed that i didn't make the case correct in my suggestion.  I am not sure if that matters (I think SQL is not case sensitive).

Comment: Double check the Date type.   Change the case to be correct.  If that all looks good, then remove the WHERE clause from the SQL, so that we get something working  :)  Meaning change the selectcommand to be
    "SELECT * FROM logistics"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Double check the Date type", but i used "Date" with capital D with no difference. When i remove the WHERE clause it works in the sense, that when a date is searched for, the entire database is created in the webgrid. So that part works :P appreciate you helping me out :)

Comment: "Double Check" means to go make sure that something is true.  In this case, i am asking that you make sure that Date has the type of DateTime in the database.  I do not know how SQL Server deals with date time formats for other than american english, so now that we've confirmed that the SQL statement works without the date test, let's try

    "SELECT * FROM logistics WHERE Date > '2001-01-01'"

And try various ways of formatting the date in single quotes, like 01/01/2001.   How do you by default write your dates?  Good luck.

Comment: I also suggested using the CONVERT function in SQL server.  I'm sure it works in SQL Server, but not sure it works in SQL Server Express, which is what i think you are using.  If that's the case, we'll know from the test above.

Comment: When specifying: Date > '05/05/2016' or using: Date > '05-05-2016'  it works just fine, showing only the entries after the selected date. Could the problem be that in the SQL statement, when comparing etc. Date > Data, it searches for a column named Data? I get this error when trying to use Date > Data.      The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = Data ]. In web matrix you can select the type in the database and i've checked that its set to type DateTime as the picture also shows http://puu.sh/oLsDY/ed7aa6518c.png :s

Comment: I also edited the initial post to reflect the changes that might have been made. The input is etc. 05/18/2016 which also works if its hardcoded into the SQL statement.

Comment: We're close.  Just change the searchterm to @0 and you will at least get the ones on or after the date.  When your are trying to put data into an SQL statement, the data you put in will always be in form of @0, @1, @2... depending on how many data elements you are trying pass in.  I edited my answer slightly to show this.